# Is there any Spring @Required annotation equivalent in EJB 3.0?

Tags: dependency-injection, ejb-3.0

Is there any equivalent annotation in EJB for @Required (Spring)? I do dependency injection using setters and I want to be sure that resource was injected (almost no probability of NullPointerException ;)). In Spring it is easy:

```
@Required
public void setProperty(Property p) {
 this.property = p;
}
```

Is there any way to do such a validation in EJB? (Maybe some other solution than annotatations). Thanks

Comment: In EJB3 you do it via @EJB and @Resource and it just works :-)

Comment: And there is no way that in some circumstances container will inject null or not do the injection at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In ejb injection is done via `@EJB` and `@Resource` (as stated above).
If the bean for the given (or auto-generated) name doesn't exist you get an error from the container (in many cases this happens at deployment time).

The only way to (maybe) get a nullpointer exception inside a ejb bean is if you try to access an injected object in the default constructor. By spec injection happens after the constructor and before the `@PostConstruct` lifecycle is called.